# What is the best way to show different form fields for different users in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

What is the best way to show different form fields for different user in ASP.NET?

Here is an example:
I have a form which has TextBox1, TextBox2, and TextBox3.
User A can only see TextBox1 and TextBox3.
User B can only see TextBox2 and TextBox3.
...

If there are a lot of users or form fields. It will be too tedious to code all the logic.
Is there any elegant way to achieve this without hand-coded logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the LoginView Control. This is a small [how-to](http://www.cerkit.com/cerkitBlog/2005/03/14/HOWTOUseTheLoginViewControlInASPNET20.aspx).

Comment: This question was asked a long time ago and the link does not show LoginView control. Is there any up to date way of handling this? My scenario is that I can have 100 plus fields on a form and I need to display fields depending on who is logged in. The business/validation rules can be different for each user as well.

Answer (score 0):

I like grouping related controls with panels, however if the differences are small between groups of users, turning controls visibility on or off might be good enough.

Just make sure you test each different scenario, as often this is where testing falls down.

If there are lots of controls, it might be worthwhile looking at creating them dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using role-based authorization, you could write something similar to [ReadWriteAuthorization](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid6B6D19ECEAFCFC088B6C46925B1E5D1C24CF147A.aspx) in CSLA.
This is an extender control which enables/disables/sets read-only or empties controls based on the user being able to read or write the specific property the control is bound to.
This could be enhanced to also show/hide controls. Of course this also means your business objects need to know which properties can (or can't) be viewed by which roles.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way is to use Profile in ASP and storing controls properties for each user in Profile.
In this way, controls properties can be loaded during page load.
Such as,

```
labelPostalCode.Text = Profile.PostalCode;
```

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taab950e.aspx